# Django: UTF-8 in form field label causes UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: django, utf-8, hebrew

Consider the following Django form:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

...

class VideoForm(forms.Form):
    link = forms.URLField(label="LINK")
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
```

This works fine, giving a form with a field whose label is `LINK`. However, when I change the link line to:

```
link = forms.URLField(label="קישור")
```

I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
...
In template /Users/adamatan/Personal/hashmabir_design/flip_classroom_hackathon/web/flipped/core/templates/
...
core/add_video.html, error at line 23
...
{% trans field.label_tag %} {{ field }}
```

How do I encode the template in utf-8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

---

```
>>> 'a'
'a'
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> 'a'
u'a'
```

See [__future__ — Future statement definitions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html?highlight=__future__#__future__).

Answer (score 1):

Setting the string in `forms.py` to unicode solved the problem:

```
link = forms.URLField(label=u"קישור")
```